# Reset password symfony 4

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony4, reset-password

I'm trying to create a reset password for users in symfony 4, I have this error

> No route found for "GET /change-password": Method Not Allowed (Allow:
>   POST)

I'm looking for help please

my Controller:

```
class ChangepasswordController extends Controller
{
private $oldpassword;
private $newpassword;

/**
 * @Route("/change-password", name="change_password", defaults={"email=null"})
 * @Method("POST")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
 * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
 * @param $email
 * @return Response
 */
public function ChangepasswordAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, $email)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(ChangepasswordType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        try {
            $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($email);


        } catch (ExceptionInterface $e) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', "Cet email n'existe pas.");
        }

        //Recuperer le nouveau mot de passe tapé par l'utilisateur
        $newpassword = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
        //recuperer l'ancien mot de passe dans la base de donnéees
        $oldpassword = $user->getPassword();

        if ($newpassword = $oldpassword) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', "Ce mot de passe est dejà utilisé.");

        } else {
            $user->setPassword($newpassword);
        }

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'votre mot de passe est bien  réinitialisé');

        # Redirection sur la page de connexion
        return $this->redirectToRoute('connexion');
    }
    return $this->render(
        'security/changemotdepasse.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You have to change @Method("POST") to @Method({"GET","POST"}), because your Action is for displaying and processing the form.

Comment: Thanks, I have another mistake

Answer (score 0):

I think GET method is not good way to reset password, you can add GET in Methode annotation to fix it but it’s bad way .

The good way is just send data by POST Method and handle it in $request

Answer (score -3):

```
@Route("/change-password", name="change_password"
```

Take care of your definition ... - !== _